# Removing CSS and js version via REGEX

Tags: php, regex

How can I remove the `?v=VersionNumber` after the filename

```
script.js?v=VersionNumber
CSS.css?v=VersionNumber
```

Expected result:

```
script.js
CSS.css
```

What I tried:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://stackoverflow.com/');
$html = preg_replace('/.js(.*)/s', '', $html);
```

Comment: $html = file_get_contents(' any website link');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your answer that you want to match digits, if you want to remove the version number for either a js or css file:

```
\.(?:js|css)\K\?v=\d+
```

The pattern matches

- `\.(?:js|css)` Match either `.js` or `.css`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\?v=\d+` match `?v=` and 1 or more digits

See a[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gwVID5/1).

```
$re = '/\.(?:js|css)\K\?v=\d+/';
$s = 'script.js?v=123
CSS.css?v=3456';
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $s);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
script.js
CSS.css
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/A3mce).

Answer (score 2):

```php
$html = preg_replace('/\?v=[[:alnum:]]*/', '', $html)
```

Tests:

- https://3v4l.org/BuEOf
- https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/E3N

---

## Only apply that to JS and CSS

```php
$html = preg_replace('/(css|js)(\?v=[[:alnum:]]*)/', '$1', $html);
```

- This pattern separates the matches to two groups (each pair of parentheses defines a group).
- In the replacement `$1` refers to the first captured group which is `(css|js)` to keep the extenstion.

Test https://3v4l.org/K3OVO

Answer (score -1):

You could use `strtok` to get the characters before a string

```
$fileURL = 'script.js?v=VersionNumber';
echo strtok($fileURL, '?');
// script.js
```

If you want to use `preg_match_all` , you could do something like below:

```
$re = '/^([^?]+)/m';
$str = 'index.js?params=something';
$str2 = 'index.jsparams=something';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
preg_match_all($re, $str2, $matches2);

var_dump($matches[0][0]); // return index.js
var_dump($matches[0][0]); // return index.jsparams=something
```

It will remove all characters after `?` . If `?` not found, it will return the original value

Comment: i'm using $n = preg_match_all('/"([^"]+?\.css)"/', $html, $matches);
if ($n !== FALSE && $n > 0) {
   // var_dump($matches[1]);
 foreach ($matches[1] as $css)
 {
  echo $css.'<br>';
 }
}

Comment: so preg_match_all not working. what i mean is after removing version the preg_match_all will works.

Comment: i'm using file_get_contents, and remove ?v=[0-9]{0,5}, so explode not working

Comment: Please see my updated answer if that works

Comment: There is no $str or $str2, there is whole html file from file get contents and i have to remove version if exist.

Answer (score -2):

```html
$html = preg_replace('/.js(\?v=[0-9]{0,15})/s', '.js', $html);
```

That's work, i just want a little improvements of the code.